# How to use keyboard keys to change videos in HTML

Tags: html

I know how to play and pause using the keys but I also want to know how I can change the videos using the keyboard keys

The code below added with my video ids allow me to play and pause using 'p' on the keyboard, but how do I change that each key plays a different video?

```
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');   
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if((e || window.event).keyCode === 112){
        vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could just change the source and load the video on keypress function.

```
vid.setAttribute("src", "some video source");
vid.load();
```

so something like:

```
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');   
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if((e || window.event).keyCode === 112){
        vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();
    } else if((e || window.event).keyCode === 39) {
        vid.setAttribute("src", "some video source");
        vid.load();
    }
};
```